# Call my custom javascript function in html

Tags: javascript, html

I can't displaying myFunction(), I already use any way to make this javascript function can working in my html, but it can't working properly

This is my html :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="melvin.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(10, 2);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my melvin.js :

```
 function myFunction(a, b) {
  return a * b;
 }
```

This is structure, I using composer also :

[image: structure]

Please help, thanks

Comment: **Do not use screenshots to show your structure**.  Include the actual code.

Comment: Check your error console, see if there's any information there.

Comment: Instead of placing your javascript in HTML. Why not put document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(10, 2); after my function?

Comment: Do you want to put the code of the function, or the result of executing the function??

Comment: ya, i forgot to read the request.. so I cant displaying the myFunction() in html, I using composer also, is the path in `<script src="melvin.js">` is wrong?

Comment: _Instead of placing...Why not put..._ @PraveenAlluri because of the separation of concerns...

Comment: Code works fine for me. What errors do you get in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by someone your code is working fine. The issue is in your function `rupiah()`.

Close the first line with `;` instead of `,` and it will work.